# How to identify an input field by an input method service?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I am implementing a custom keyboard and therefore use an input method service. In the `onStartInput()` method I am able to identify the app, the keyboard is used in, by the `packageName` of the `EditorInfo` parameter.

I would like to identy the input field to allow the user to execute certain actions depending on which field he has selected. For example if he uses app XY and select the first field their should be different keys offered to the user than when he selected the second or third field. All fields are regular text fields. To be able to do so, it is necessary to get an ID of the input field.

Does anyone now a solution for this?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Can you provide an example? What exactly is the information you need about the editor field? Do you have control over the *app XY*? There are several other fields in [`EditorInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo) which give information on what functionality the keyboard should provide for each editor field.

Comment: No, I do not have control over the app XY, as this keyboard can be used in any app that is installed on the system. If you think about an email client, I want to distiguish between the email address field and the text field. I do not need to know what kind of field it is, but the user should be able to save the id of the text field in the app and be able to assign a certain keyboard layout to saved text field ids. So I just need a way to be able to identify if it is the address or message field the next he focused a text field.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you want to identify the InputType of the keyboard to know which type of keyboard to show to a user. You can also do it in the `onStartInputView` like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {

        super.onStartInputView(info, restarting);
        int inputType = info.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS;
                //Some input types have variation 
                //like passwords for InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                //to handle that:
        int inputVariation = info.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;

        switch (inputType){
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
                Log.i("InputType", "onStartInputView: Text");
                
                if(inputVariation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD){
                    //letter input method for passwords
                }
                break;
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
                Log.i("InputType", "onStartInputView: number");
                break;
            //Case ...:
            default:
                //Todo: what ever you prefer

        }
    }
```

For more information [check out this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method#handle-different-input-types)